# How to print mean, median and sd on boxplots in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following boxplot and I'm trying to print the mean, median and sd values on each box, how does that work? Is there a simple way or a simple parameter in geom_boxplot to make this happen? 
Thanks

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(x=class,y=cty))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want them on there as text? Or displayed with points/lines/markers somehow?

Comment: @Marius as text.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to put text in a table, not on your plot. Note that the median is already plotted, you could add a visual indication of the mean and sd with `geom_pointrange`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll first need to calculate the summary statistics:

```
library(dplyr)

summ <- mpg %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(cty), median = median(cty), sd = sd(cty))
```

Then use that data frame in your `geom_label` call.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = cty)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_label(data = summ, aes(x = class, y = mean, 
    label = paste("Mean: ", round(mean, 1), "\nMedian: ", median, "\nSD: ", round(sd, 1))))
```

[image]

Not a good looking chart, but you just need to play around with the size and colours to pretty it up, or maybe use `geom_text` instead of `geom_label`.